# Is $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ undefined at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I have read that any function (correction: expression) divided by zero is undefined, so is $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ undefined at $x=0$?

Out of curiosity, I entered $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ into Wolfram Alpha, and the plot does not show any sign of being undefined at $x=0$.

Comment: The function has a removable singularity. If we add the point $(0,1)$ , it becomes a smooth function. But it is not defined at $x=0$ since division by zero is forbidden. The singularity is however not visible unless we make a circle around the point $(0,1)$ which is the common way to indicate such a case.

Comment: A funny thing about the "singularity" here: writing out $\sin x$ as a Taylor series allows the factor of $1/x$ to cancel out, and there is no longer a singularity.

Comment: @WilliamBarnes That's what "removable singularity" means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function and an expression are two different things. A function has a domain (and codomain), and for each element of its domain assigns a value from its codomain.

For some functions, this assignment may be denoted by an expression, for all or some of its domain.

As such, "$\frac{\sin x}{x}$" isn't a function. It's an expression. On the other hand,

> The function with the real numbers as domain and codomain, given by $x\mapsto\frac{\sin x}x$.

is almost a function. Phrased this way, it is undefined at $x=0$, even though that's an element of the domain, and this makes it not a function. There are two common ways to mend this and make the above into a bona fide function. One is

> The function with the real numbers except $0$ as domain and the real numbers as codomain, given by $x\mapsto\frac{\sin x}x$.

The other is

> The function with the real numbers as domain and codomain, given by $x\mapsto\frac{\sin x}x$ for $x\neq 0$, and $0\mapsto 1$.

There is no way to just look at "$\frac{\sin x}x$" and know which one of these (or something different) is intended.

Comment: Does it even make sense to consider $\sin(x)/x$ if $x\in\mathbb{R}$, rather than $x\in\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$? I feel uncomfortable saying that $x=0$ could be part of the domain of $\sin(x)/x$, even if we are not talking about functions per se.

Comment: I think the term domain should be reserved for functions, and since a function is a set of ordered pairs of elements, $f(x)=\sin(x)/x$ can only be well-defined if from from the outset we state that $x \neq 0$. But I'm curious to hear your view on the matter.

Comment: I don't quite agree to say that $x=0$ is in the domain. I'd rather say that the domain is $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, and that $\dfrac{\sin x}x$ is a *partial function* over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Joe Does my answer not address this exact concern in quite some detail?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am pretty certain that this is explicitly addressed in my answer.

Comment: It's possible that you just phrased it in a way that was liable to confusion. So, are you saying that $x \mapsto \sin(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is in a sense 'almost' a well-defined function, but actually the domain has to be restricted further to $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: @Joe That's what "is almost a function" is meant to signify. But yes, it might've been a bit unclear.

Comment: That makes sense. I think it was the bit where you said 'even though that's an element of domain' which was confusing, since we were essentially talking about a pseudo-function. It would have made more sense to me if you had written 'but $0$ shouldn't be in the domain of $\sin(x)/x$, so in order to make the function well-defined, we have to stipulate that $x \neq 0$'. But it's fine now that you have clarified your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Confusingingly, people often talk about the behaviour of this function as $x$ *approaches* $0$ (but is not equal to it). This can be easily be confused with evaluating $\sin(0)/0$, which is non-sensical. However, we can say that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1 \, .
$$
Roughly speaking, the above expression means 'as $x$ gets closer and closer to $0$, $\sin(x)/x$ gets closer and closer to $1$'. It does not mean that if $x=0$, then $\sin(x)/x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

A function is defined *on a domain*. Since we are (implicitly) considering functions from the real line with values in the real line, you cannot divide by zero, hence the domain of the function is $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$.

Plotting the function, you probably see that **the limit** of $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ is well defined for $x \rightarrow 0$, since limits are defined in a neighborhood of a point that **does not** contain the point itself (as you explain in your nice blog :) )

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Alpha explicitly says that the domain (in the reals) is

$$\{x\in\mathbb R:x\ne 0\}.$$

Don't trust a plot blindly.

Answer (score 1):

It has a *limit* but not a *value*.  That is, we can all see where the graph is going.  The value of the function will be infinitely close to 1 as $x$ gets infinitely close to 0.  This means that it is generally okay to use 1 as the value for $\frac{\sin(0)}{0}$ but it is technically non-existent precisely at the number 0.  In nearly all applications, it will work just fine.

As @Peter noted in the comments, this discontinuity is so small that it won't show up on graphs unless the graphing software is written to explicitly make it obvious to you.